Creating a correlated sequence of 1s and 0s where the frequency of 1s occuring is fixed
I want to generate two sequences of length of 100 consisting of 1s and 0s. The sequences should exhibit both correlated case and uncorrelated case but the number of 1s should be the same in both the sequence. For instance

[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] -> # of 1s = 14/36
[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0] -> # of 1s = 14/36

I tried creating this using markov chains, where I assume that for both the cases the initial distribution is stationary distribution which is common [0.2, 0.8]. Now I generate sequences with transition matrices as follows:
$T_{uncorr} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.2 & 0.8 \\
0.2 & 0.8
\end{bmatrix}
$ and $T_{corr} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.992 & 0.008 \\
0.002 & 0.998
\end{bmatrix}
$.
For the uncorrelated sequence of length 100, I get # of 1s ~ 80
But for the correlated sequence of length 100, I get # of 1s that vary from 0.4 to 1.0 with majority being 1.0. How do I ensure that I get a correlated sequence of fixed frequency or near fixed frequency?

If the Markov process can generate sequences that would be "rejected" as not meeting some criterion, note that the resulting distribution of outcomes will not be described by the Markov process you defined in the first place. Essentially, if the output of the process consists only of sequences with a frequency of exactly (or however close you like to) 0.8, it almost certainly did not come from the given transition matrix. You can alternately flip a double-headed and double-tailed coin to ensure you get 50% heads, but that's not representative of just flipping a fair coin.

One implicit issue is whether a correct answer to your question will be useful or correct for your application, so please tell us why you want to generate such a sequence.  Another issue is that there are many different ways to solve this problem.  As an example, generate any Gaussian time series $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{100})$ with any correlation structure you like and then for any target count $k,$ (numerically) find a threshold $t$ for which exactly $k$ of the $x_i$ exceed $k.$  Replace those $x_i$ with $1$ and the rest with $0.$ You need to narrow the possible answers somehow.

@whuber My application involves performing certain tasks based on a binary sequence. I have an algorithm that generates a sequence, which I want to compare with the two sequences mentioned above. I would be grateful if you could guide me to a link where I can read more about the method you suggested or provide sample code. Thank you in advance.

This is a standard spatial model for binary data, as described at http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/geoRglm/index.html (for instance).

@whuber Thanks for your answer. I tried out your earlier suggestion and I wanted to confirm with you if I got it right (I am new to this and so would love an expert's stamp). So I created a multivariate gaussian distribution whose mean is [0,0,0,....100 times] and whose covariance matrix is given by one of these kernels which is of shape 100x100. Once I get a realisation of this dist., I sort them and find 20th largest value (threshold). Varying the params of kernel function, I can get my two desired seq. Am I right?

Yes: but be aware that most measures of the correlation (such as the usual Pearson coefficient) for the binary values will differ from the corresponding correlation of the underlying Gaussian process.  They usually will be close, though.

@whuber Thanks a ton!
